# Pass dynamic values of Select option to database in php

Tags: php, mysql

In my code there are departments in the respective college, colleges are under Academic President and Purchasing sector. Department plan to purchase items like laptop, desktop, printer, copier and send it to the respective college. Many departments may plan the same items (may the quantity different). Then the college approves and sends it to Academic President. When it is at the Academic President level I need to sum the same items of different departments in the same college i.e group by college and item type. here is the code to Display for Academic President page for approval

```
$data= mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT dbuims_college.*,
dbuims_item_category.*, dbuims_plan.*, SUM(plan_quantity) as Total  FROM `dbuims_plan`
 INNER JOIN dbuims_college ON  dbuims_plan.college_id= dbuims_college.college_id
 INNER JOIN  dbuims_item_category ON dbuims_item_category.item_category_id = dbuims_plan.item_category_id
 WHERE  plan_status_college='1' AND  plan_status_vice_president ='1' AND plan_status_asset_director='0' AND purchased_status='0'
 GROUP BY dbuims_plan.item_category_id, dbuims_plan.college_id
/////////////////////////////////////
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $college_name;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $item_category_name;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $asset_category_code;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $plan_date1;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $Amount;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $asset_category_spec;?></td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $plan_id;?>" name="plan_id<?php echo $plan_id;?>">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $dept_id;?>" name="dept_id<?php echo $dept_id;?>">
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $item_category_id;?>" name="item_category_id<?php echo $item_category_id;?>">
    <select name="plan_status_asset_director<?php echo $item_category_id; ?>" id="asset_category_code" class="form-control" >
                                        <option value="0">Select </option>
                                        <option value="1">Approve </option>
                                        <option value="-1">Reject </option>
</select>                   
</td>
<td> <textarea name='rejection_reason' class='form-control'></textarea></td>
</tr>
////////////////////////////////////////
approve php code

$abc1=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT *  FROM `dbuims_plan`

 WHERE  plan_status_college='1' AND  plan_status_vice_president ='1' AND plan_status_asset_director='0' AND purchased_status='0'
 GROUP BY dbuims_plan.item_category_id, dbuims_plan.college_id")or die ("query 2 incorrect.......");

 while(list($plan_id,$item_category_id,$plan_quantity,$plan_date,$plan_date1,$plan_modified_date,
$plan_remark,$user_id,$dept_id,$college_id,$vpresident_id,$plan_status_college,$plan_status_Institute,
$plan_status_vice_president,$plan_status_asset_director,$item_category_type,$rejection_reason,$purchased_status)=mysqli_fetch_array($abc1))

{
  $plan_status_asset_director=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,check_input($_POST['plan_status_asset_director'.$item_category_id]));
    //$plan_id=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,check_input($_POST['plan_id'.$item_category_id]));
    $item_category_id_i=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,check_input($_POST['item_category_id'.$item_category_id]));
    //$dept_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,check_input($_POST['dept_id'.$dept_id]));
    $rejection_reason =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,check_input($_POST['rejection_reason']));
if($plan_status_asset_director !="")
 echo '<script> alert("'." plan status asset director ".$plan_status_asset_director." item id ".$item_category_id." plan id ".$plan_id.'");</script>';

//$sql_plan=mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE dbuims_plan SET plan_status_asset_director='$plan_status_asset_director' WHERE  plan_id ='$plan_id'");

//header ("Location: $padirector_asset_plan_request");
}
/////////////////////////////////
```

The problem is since I have grouped by category and college in approve code some plan id is undefinde.
Any othe option or modification of this code? 
Thank you you time and wellingness to read this and help me!

Comment: Why do you have HTML code in the middle of the call to `mysqli_query()`? Did you leave something out when copying the code?

Comment: Please close your Text Literals !! The first Query for a start

Comment: to display fetched values of the above php $date variable results.

Comment: A nice feature of this site is that it colour codes (sorry, don't know the correct term) code, which makes dumb errors easy to spot

Comment: For further help, please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)